# Debugging a .desktop file for launching Spyder within venv in Debian 12

Tags: linux, bash, shell, desktop, gnome

I need help debugging a .desktop file I've created for launching the Spyder IDE within a virtual environment in Debian 12. Here are the contents of my `spyder.desktop` file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Spyder IDE
Comment=The Scientific Python Development Environment
Keywords=ide;spyder;python;
Exec=/home/<userid>/code/scripts/spyder/launch_spyder.sh
Icon=/home/<userid>/Pictures/icons/spyder/spyder.svg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

And here is the `launch_spyder.sh` script pointed to by the above shortcut.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source $WORKON_HOME/python-env/bin/activate 
spyder
deactivate
```

Interestingly, *both* the shell script and the `gtk-launch spyder` commands work from my default bash terminal. Furthermore, when I perform a keyword search, the desktop icon also pops up as expected, but executing it does nothing. I'd be interested to know how to debug and troubleshoot what's going on when I attempt to launch the application this way.

Please note that I also tried including a `source $HOME/.bashrc` line in the shell script, thinking that it might help to replicate the exact environment from which the script successfully launches when run from the terminal, but that hasn't helped with the desktop method either.

Thanks for reading.